# Area of a Triangle in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, area

I find this question quite tricky, and I don't know if this kind of treatment is right.
I was asked about the area of a triangle formed by the points: $A:(1,2,-3,3)$; $B:(3,-6,-4,2)$; and $C:(-3,-16,-4,0)$. The only way I could make a reason out of this would be getting all the $2\times2$ matrices within the matrix M whose columns are AB and AC, getting their determinants, and finally dividing it by two. Is this procedure right? I will write the processes below:

Firstly, get vectors AB and AC:

$AB = (2,-8,-1,-1)$

$AC = (-4,-18,-1,-3)$

Secondly, construct matrix M:
\begin{equation}
M_{4,2}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -4  \\
-8 & -18  \\
-1  & -1  \\
-1 & -3 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Thirdly, get all the $2\times2$ determinants within M:
\begin{equation}
S_{2}=
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -4 \\ 
-8 & -18
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -4 \\ 
-1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -4 \\ 
-1 & -3
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
-8 & -18 \\ 
-1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
-8 & -18 \\ 
-1 & -3
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\ 
-1 & -3
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

Forthly, dividing by two, and getting the absolute value (Area=$|\frac{S_{2}}{2}|$):

Area$=43$

Comment: I am not familiar with this procedure, but my approach would be to use Heron's formula: it gives you the area of any triangle solely in terms of the lengths of its sides.

Comment: Could you explain how you got the idea of adding up minors?

Comment: Well, I got this idea of adding the minors from the notion of area we get from determinants. Area is the determinant of the space generated by two vectors and volume is the determinant of the space generated by three vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $n$-vectors $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb R^m$, the $n$-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is given by $\sqrt{\det(G)}$, where $G$ is the [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant) given by $G=(\langle x_i, x_j\rangle)_{ij}$.

Hence, we get
$$
A = \frac{\sqrt{\det(X^T X)}}{2}=35,\quad \text{where}\quad X=\begin{pmatrix}2&-4\\-8&-18\\-1&-1\\-1&-3\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: My God! I completelly forgot about the Gram determinant! This is the thing I was missing! Thank you very much!

Comment: much simpler approach than mine (+1)

Answer (score 2):

As @Unit commented, Herons formula might be an easier bet, we have:
$$\overrightarrow{AB}=\begin{pmatrix}3-1\\-6-2\\-4+3\\2-3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-8\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\right|=\sqrt{2^2+8^2+1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{70}$$
$$\overrightarrow{BC}=\begin{pmatrix}-6\\-10\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow\left|\overrightarrow{BC}\right|=\sqrt{6^2+10^2+2^2}=\sqrt{140}$$
$$\overrightarrow{AC}=\begin{pmatrix}-4\\-18\\-1\\-3\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow\left|\overrightarrow{AC}\right|=\sqrt{4^2+18^2+1^2+3^2}=\sqrt{350}$$

---

We can say that the Area of the triangle is:
$$A_{abc}=\sqrt{S\left(S-|\overrightarrow{AC}|\right)\left(S-|\overrightarrow{BC}|\right)\left(S-|\overrightarrow{AB}|\right)}$$
where:
$$S=\frac{|\overrightarrow{AC}|+|\overrightarrow{AB}|+|\overrightarrow{BC}|}{2}$$

Comment: Right! I could have used Heron's formula too!

Answer (score 2):

In the  $m$-D space , we generalize the cross product by the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivector).

Given two vectors ${\bf a} = \vec {AB} , \; {\bf b} = \vec {AC} $, expressed in the base system
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf a} = a_{\,1} {\bf e}_{\,1}  + a_{\,2} {\bf e}_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + a_{\,m} {\bf e}_{\,m}   \cr 
  & {\bf b} = b_{\,1} {\bf e}_{\,1}  + b_{\,2} {\bf e}_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + b_{\,m} {\bf e}_{\,m}  \cr} 
$$
their wedge product is defined to be the *2-vector* (or *2-blade*)
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf w} = {\bf a} \wedge {\bf b} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {a_{\,1} {\bf e}_{\,1}  + a_{\,2} {\bf e}_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + a_{\,m} {\bf e}_{\,m} } \right)
 \wedge \left( {b_{\,1} {\bf e}_{\,1}  + b_{\,2} {\bf e}_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + b_{\,m} {\bf e}_{\,m} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k,j\, \le m} {a_{\,k} b_{\,j} {\bf e}_{\,k}  \wedge {\bf e}_{\,j} }
  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k < j\, \le m} {\left( {a_{\,k} b_{\,j}  - a_{\,j} b_{\,k} } \right){\bf e}_{\,k}  \wedge {\bf e}_{\,j} }  \cr} 
$$
a total of $\binom {m}{2}$ base components since, by definition
$$
{\bf e}_{\,k}  \wedge {\bf e}_{\,j}  =  - \,{\bf e}_{\,j}  \wedge {\bf e}_{\,k}
 \quad {\bf e}_{\,k}  \wedge {\bf e}_{\,k}  = 0
$$

The magnitude of $\bf w$ is defined as
$$
\left| {\bf w} \right| = \left| {{\bf a} \wedge {\bf b}} \right|
 = \sqrt {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k < j\, \le m}
 {\left( {a_{\,k} b_{\,j}  - a_{\,j} b_{\,k} } \right)^{\,2} } } 
$$
So, for $m=2$ we get
$$
\left| {\bf w} \right| = \left| {a_{\,1} b_{\,2}  - a_{\,2} b_{\,1} } \right|
$$
which is the area of the parallelogram with sides defined by ${\bf a}, {\bf b}$,
and for $m=3$
$$
\left| {\bf w} \right|
 = \sqrt {\left| {a_{\,1} b_{\,2}  - a_{\,2} b_{\,1} } \right|^{\,2} 
 + \left| {a_{\,1} b_{\,3}  - a_{\,3} b_{\,1} } \right|^{\,2} 
 + \left| {a_{\,2} b_{\,3}  - a_{\,3} b_{\,2} } \right|^{\,2} } 
$$
which corresponds to the modulus of the cross-product ${\bf a} \times {\bf b}$,
and therefore again to the area of the parallelogram defined by by ${\bf a}, {\bf b}$.

And the above generalizes to ${\mathbb R}^m$ where the magnitude of the wedge product
of two vectors equal the area of the 2D parallelotope defined by the two vectors, and where
the magnitude of each component represents the area of the projection of the parallelotope onto each coordinate
plane.

But for what concerns the modulus, we can also express it in polar way (spherical oordinates) and get
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left| {\,{\bf a} \wedge {\bf b}\,} \right|
 = \left| {\,{\bf a}\,} \right|\left| {\,{\bf b}\,} \right|\sin \left( {\angle {\bf a},{\bf b}} \right)
 = a\,b\sin \left( {\angle {\bf a},{\bf b}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left| {\,{\bf a}\,} \right|\left| {\,{\bf b}_{\, \bot {\bf a}} \,} \right| =   \cr 
  &  = a\sqrt {b^{\,2}  - \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {{\bf a} \over a}} \right)^{\,2} }
  = \sqrt {a^{\,2} b^{\,2}  - \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}} \right)^{\,2} }  \cr} 
$$
where
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf b} = {\bf b}_{\,\backslash \backslash {\bf a}}  + {\bf b}_{\, \bot {\bf a}}  \hfill \cr 
  {\bf b}_{\,\backslash \backslash {\bf a}}  = \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}/a} \right){\bf a}/a \hfill \cr 
  {\bf b}_{\, \bot {\bf a}}  = {\bf b} - {\bf b}_{\,\backslash \backslash {\bf a}}
  = {\bf b} - \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}/a} \right){\bf a}/a \hfill \cr 
  \left| {{\bf b}_{\,\backslash \backslash {\bf a}} } \right|^{\,2}
  = \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}/a} \right)^{\,2}
  = b^{\,2} \cos ^{\,2} \left( {\angle {\bf a},{\bf b}} \right) \hfill \cr 
  \left| {{\bf b}_{\, \bot {\bf a}} } \right|^{\,2}
  = \left( {{\bf b} - \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}/a} \right){\bf a}/a} \right) \cdot
 \left( {{\bf b} - \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}/a} \right){\bf a}/a} \right) =  \hfill \cr 
   = \left| {\bf b} \right|^{\,2}  - 2\left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}/a} \right)^{\,2}
  + \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}/a} \right)^{\,2}
  = b^{\,2}  - \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}/a} \right)^{\,2}  =  \hfill \cr 
   = b^{\,2} \sin ^{\,2} \left( {\angle {\bf a},{\bf b}} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
So in your case,
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf a} = \left( {2, - 8, - 1, - 1} \right)\quad {\bf b} = \left( { - 4, - 18, - 1, - 3} \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf w} = {\bf a} \wedge {\bf b}
 =  - 68{\bf e}_{\,1} {\bf e}_{\,2}  - 6{\bf e}_{\,1} {\bf e}_{\,3}  - 10{\bf e}_{\,1} {\bf e}_{\,4}
  - 10{\bf e}_{\,2} {\bf e}_{\,3}  + 6{\bf e}_{\,2} {\bf e}_{\,4}  + 2{\bf e}_{\,3} {\bf e}_{\,4}  \cr} 
$$
and the area of the **parallelogram** defined by $A,B,C$ will be given by
$$
\left| {\bf w} \right| = A_{\,ABCA'}
  = \sqrt {68^{\,2}  + 6^{\,2}  + 10^{\,2}  + 10^{\,2}  + 6^{\,2}  + 4^{\,2} }  = 70
$$
while that of the **triangle** will be half of that.

Comment: To connect this to OPs approach: Instead of summing the minors, this shows that we need to sum the squares of the minors, take the square root and then divide by $2$ to get the area of the triangle.

Comment: Yes, correct, see the wikipedia link given

Comment: The minor calculation yields $A = \tfrac 1 2 \sqrt{68^2+6^2+10^2+10^2+6^2+2^2} = 35$. I think you made a mistake in your calculation.

Comment: @Christoph :  you are right, thanks for signalling .. I took the components of $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ wrongly (do not know why ..): I will amend my answer accordingly

Comment: @Christoph and with the right components for $\bf a, \bf b$, now it checks with yours